# Solve can not solve the equation correctly in Reals

Tags: equation-solving, trigonometry

Here is the error I found.

```
r = 3;
Solve[Sqrt[(r^2 Cos[m Pi] - x)^2 + (r^2 Sin[m Pi])^2] == 10 && x > 0 &&
   0 <= m <= 2, x, Reals]
```

`{{x -> ConditionalExpression[ 9 Cos[m \[Pi]] + Sqrt[100 - 81 Sin[m \[Pi]]^2],  0 <= m < 1/2 || 1/2 < m < 3/2 || 3/2 < m <= 2]}}`

Mathematica says $m \neq \frac {1} {2}$  and $m \neq \frac {3} {2}$

But I beleieve it can be equal to these 2 numbers.

1. When $ r=3,m=  \frac {1} {2} $,

$ x = \sqrt {19} $

2. When $ r=3,m=  \frac {3} {2} $,

$ x = \sqrt {19} $

Comment: If you had used the Weierstrass substitution, you might have less problems.

Comment: @J.M. How can I use Weierstrass substitution? Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the Weierstrass substitution, we temporarily let $m\pi=2\arctan u$, which corresponds to restricting $m$ to $-1<m\leq 1$. Thus,

```
With[{r = 3},
     Simplify[Solve[Sqrt[TrigExpand[(r^2 Cos[2 ArcTan[u]] - x)^2 +
                                    (r^2 Sin[2 ArcTan[u]])^2]] == 10 &&
                    x > 0, x, Reals] /. u -> Tan[m π/2]]]
   {{x -> 1/2 (18 Cos[m π] + Sqrt[238 + 162 Cos[2 m π]])}}
```

which is equivalent to what Bob got in his answer:

```
9 Cos[m π] + Sqrt[100 - 81 Sin[m π]^2] == x /. First[%] // Simplify
   True
```

Answer (score 3):

When you experience a problem with a function check out its options.

```
Clear["Global`*"]

r = 3;

sys = Sqrt[(r^2 Cos[m Pi] - x)^2 + (r^2 Sin[m Pi])^2] == 10 && x > 0 && 
   0 <= m <= 2;

Solve[sys, x, Reals]
```

[image]

Using the option [`MaxExtraConditions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxExtraConditions.html)

```
Solve[sys, x, Reals, MaxExtraConditions -> All]
```

[image]

Or use [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce.html)

```
Reduce[sys, x, Reals]
```

[image]

Comment: Why not `{{x -> ConditionalExpression[ 9 Cos[m \[Pi]] + Sqrt[100 - 81 Sin[m \[Pi]]^2]}}` instead?

Comment: -What is `sol`? Can you specify it? I can't find `sol` in your answer.

Comment: @kile - The result is given in the form that the internal algorithms came up with. Presumably for reasons of efficiency, it did not try to find a simpler representation. The simpler form would be `{x -> ConditionalExpression[9*Cos[m*Pi] + Sqrt[100 - 81*Sin[m*Pi]^2],  0 <= m <= 2]}`